# Condition for finitely many bound states in one dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, potential, schroedinger-equation, s-matrix-theory

This came up in the context of the inverse scattering transform for the KdV equation. My primary reference, a set of [lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/md327/ISlecture_notes_2012.pdf) on integrable systems by Maciej Dunajski, makes the claim that the one-dimensional Schrodinger equation has only finitely many bound states if the potential satisfies

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1 + \lvert x \rvert) \lvert V(x) \rvert dx < \infty.
$$

I tried looking at different sources, but everything I managed to find states this without proof. Why does the above condition imply finitely many bound states?

These are the places I found this statement repeated:

S. Novikov, S.V. Manakov, L.P. Pitaevskii, & V.E. Zakharov (1984) *Theory of
Solitons: The Inverse Scattering Method*, Consultants Bureau, New York.

[T. Aktosun, M. Klaus & C. van der Mee (1998) *On the number of bound states for the one-dimensional Schrodinger equation*, J. Math. Phys., 39 (9) (1998)](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.532510) (implicitly assumed, I think)

Comment: What is the meaning of $1+|x|$ if $x$ has a dimension? In other terms how do you adimemsion it ?

Comment: If $x$ is dimensionful, one can add a constant of the same dimension instead of adding $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a partial answer.

1. Ref. 1 essentially writes:

   > Consider the class of potentials $u(x)$ such that
   > $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dx~(1 +|x|)|u(x)|  ~<~\infty, \tag{2.5a}$$
   > which of course implies that $$|u(x)| ~\to ~0  \quad\text{as}\quad |x|~\to~\infty.\tag{2.5b}$$
   > This condition (2.5a) guaranties that
   > $$\text{there exists only a finite number of discrete energy levels}\tag{2.5c} $$
   > (thus it rules out both the harmonic oscillator and the hydrogen atom).
2. Condition (2.5a) is called the *Faddeev condition,* cf. Ref. 2. Eq. (2.5b) does *not* follow from eq. (2.5a), as counterexamples  shows (e.g. in the spirit of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331976/2451) Phys.SE post). In this answer we will assume eq. (2.5b) independently.
3. Let us split the potential $u=u^+-u^-$ in its [positive & negative parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts). We may assume w.l.o.g. that $u=-u^-\leq 0$ since the positive part only (weakly) decreases the number of bound states, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267866/2451) Phys.SE post.
4. Ref. 3 lists a sufficient condition for eq. (2.5c) as
   $$  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dx \sqrt{u^-(x)}  ~<~\infty. \tag{A}$$
   This can heuristically be understood from the WKB estimate for the number of bound states
   $$ N ~\approx~ \iint_{H(x,p)\leq 0} \frac{dx~dp}{h} ~=~\frac{2}{h}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dx \sqrt{2m u^-(x)}.\tag{B}$$
   Eq. (B) can be trusted in the large-$N$ limit, cf. the [correspondence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle).
5. The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)
   $$  \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dx \sqrt{u^-(x)}\right)^2  ~\leq~ \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! \frac{dx}{(1 +|x|)^{1+\varepsilon}}}_{<\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dx~(1 +|x|)^{1+\varepsilon}u^-(x) \tag{C}$$
   yields the following sufficient condition
   $$ \exists \varepsilon>0:~~\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dx~(1 +|x|)^{1+\varepsilon}u^-(x) ~<~\infty \tag{D}$$
   for eq. (A). Speaking in heuristic terms, it is reassuring that both conditions (2.5a) & (A) indicate that $u^-(x)$ should morally fall off quicker than $|x|^{-2}$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

References:

1. M. Dunajski, [*Integrable systems*](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/md327/ISlecture_notes_2012.pdf), lecture notes, 2012, p. 28.
2. P.G. Drazin & R.S. Johnson, *Solitons: An Introduction,* 2nd edition, 1989; eq. (3.2).
3. A. Messiah, [*QM*](https://archive.org/details/QuantumMechanicsVolumeI), Vol. 1, 1967; p. 106.
4. S. Novikov, S.V. Manakov, L.P. Pitaevskii & V.E. Zakharov *Theory of Solitons: The Inverse Scattering Method,* 1984.