# What potentials have infinitely many bound states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, potential, schroedinger-equation

Some potentials have only finitely many bound states (the finite square and delta function are two good examples) Others have infinitely many bound states (for example the infinite square well and $1/r$ hydrogen atom potential). What is a condition that guarantees a potential will have infinitely many bound states?

Comment: Related question in 1D: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/485632/2451

Comment: What do you mean by "the" condition? What makes you think that there is only one such condition?

Comment: You raise a good point.  In fact I think it's likely there are many equivalent conditions. Editing to "a" condition instead.

Comment: That is still too broad of a question for this site's format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer: The first chapter of Chadan and Sabatier’s ‘Inverse problems in quantum scattering theory’ explicitly defines so-called regular potentials

> ...to avoid the occurrence of some unnecessary complications (**infinitely bound states etc**). [emphasis added]

If we consider the scattering of a particle of mass m off a central potential, regular potentials are those that satisfy

$$\int_b^\infty |V(r)|r\,\mathrm dr < \infty$$ for $b \geq 0.$

So this is sufficient to *avoid* an infinite number of bound states for central potentials.